# Automatic invoices in Klarna M2 module

Tags: magento2, klarna

Stack: Magento 2.4.5
Klarna: 1.1.9 (klarna/m2-klarna) with only the Klarna payments activated.

We are currently using the Magento2 Klarna module, supposedly made by Adobe. I have a question regarding the order flow since the Klarna support seems to not know the answers. I am wondering:

**1. is it correct that the klarna module does not auomatically generate an invoice after an order is placed?**

We are experiencing the following order flow:

1. A customer places an order in the m2 store with klarna as a selected payment method.
2. The order is placed on processing, but the invoice is not generated. To generate an invoice we have to manually go to Invoice and use the Amount: Capture Online.
3. After this, the invoice is created

**2. Can anyone confirm from their own experience that the Klarna order flow works as
above?**

**3. Is there a way to make sure the invoice is automatically created (and the amount captured )**

**4. How is it possible that the order get sets on processing if an invoice or a shipment does not exist yet. I always thought those were requirements for the processing status.**

Thank you for the clarification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't auto generate invoices.

You may want to tap into the place order event and check to see if it's Klarna as payment method and from there create an online invoice.

Klarna sets the order status as processing.